# Is a Unix timestamp from client JavaScript calculation relative to the user's timezone?

Tags: java, time, timezone, jodatime, unix-timestamp

I want to convert two client times, represented by unix timestamps, to a standardized server time, represented in UTC time zone.

I want to do this using the Java Joda time library.

So if I have two clients in two different timezones and I use JavaScript code to get the Unix timestamp for each and pass the long integer value to the Java code on the server (UTC time zone), do I first need to convert those times from the user's timezone to the server timezone if I want to store them as comparable dates, or does Unix timestamp mean that if I convert them to a Joda DateTime on the server (as below), it will automatically create a DateTime for each that is equivalent to the server's timezone?

```
long clientTime = 1326329941540; // passed from client to server
DateTime clientTimeAsJoda = new DateTime(clientTime); 
// (A) Does this convert clientTimeAsJoda to server time zone?
```

or do I need to do something like this:

```
long clientTime = 1326329941540; // passed from client to server
DateTime clientTimeAsJoda = new DateTime(clientTime).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC); 
// (B) Does this convert clientTimeAsJoda to server time zone?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unix timestamps are independent of timezone; they represent the number of seconds since a specific instant called the "epoch", namely, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. (Your value is actually a number of milliseconds rather than seconds, but the idea is the same.) So no, you shouldn't need to worry about the client's time-zone for this.